# How to start Java program as a daemon using Jsvc

Tags: java, linux, daemon, jsvc

I am using Jsvc to start a java program that implements the Daemon interface. However when I issue the command

```
/usr/bin/jsvc -user walikha -home $JAVE_HOME -outfile out.file -errfile '$1'   Jooist.Server.jar Main
```

However the command silently executes and displays the prompt. How can I detect if the daemon is running? In the Java executable the  init, start, stop and destroy functions just print to a log file using Log4J. The log file is not created and there is absolutely no indication that the service is running. Am I missing something, or have I left out something when configuring and installing Jsvc?

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same problem. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Modify your command to include options "-outfile" and "-errfile" and provide your own path to the log files.

```
/usr/bin/jsvc -outfile app.out -errfile app.err -user walikha -home $JAVE_HOME -outfile out.file -errfile '$1'   Jooist.Server.jar Main
```

Comment: The original question contains both `-outfile` and `-errfile`

Answer (score 0):

You can start a service as daemon by adding your application in `/etc/init.d/ start/stop` scripts.

Comment: Would that give the option of gracefully shutdown a java service ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-debug` switch and see what's going on. However, it looks like you've missed including `commons-daemon-1.0.10.jar` in your classpath.